# json_encode wrapping everything in ''. How to solve

Tags: php, json

Iam trying to send POST data using JSON. However, I am running into an issue I cannot solve. Here is the code in question:

```
$params = array('payment' => array(
                              'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                              'memo'    => (string)$memo
                             ),
               );

$content = json_encode($params);

var_dump($content);
break;
```

$content is then being outputted as:

```
'{"payment":{"amount":"10.00","memo":"1234"}}'
```

What I **need** it to output is like:

```
{"payment":{"amount":"10.00","memo":"1234"}}
```

This has to be something simple; just i just cannot figure it out. Help please

Comment: Instead of var_dump, use echo or print.

Comment: Actually, `var_dump` would output `string(44) "{"payment":{"amount":"10.00","memo":"1234"}}"`, and not just the 'extra' quotes, as you said..

Comment: $params = array(
                  'payment' => array(
                       'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                       'memo'    => (string)$memo
                  ),
            );

echo json_encode($params);
break;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_encode with echo

```
$params = array(
                  'payment' => array(
                       'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                       'memo'    => (string)$memo
                  ),
            );

echo json_encode($params);
break;
```